# XCUITest testing a label that includes new lines

Tags: xcuitest

I am testing the existence of some screen text on a UILabel. The text I am testing against includes a number of new lines.

If I were to remove the new lines from the string in the codebase the test passes, but with the new lines it doesn't, e.g.

`let successMessage = app.staticTexts["Your reward has been saved\nto your account balance.\n\nYou can now view your balance."]`

`XCTAssertTrue(successMessage.waitForExistence(timeout: 1))`

How can I get around this? Putting the expected string into a multiline string didn't work.

Comment: Try using the test recorder to see how it formats it? Copy + paste from there! 

Comment: @MikeCollins - Thanks Mike. Yes, I tried that and it is formatted exactly as above. I think I will have to put this down as a bug.

Comment: XCUITest? A bug!? Nahhhh ;)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add your own accessibility identifier to this staticText? One that doesn't contain newlines?

Comment: @MikeCollins - Yes, this is something I had not considered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this too, in the console I could obtain the element with newlines encoded into the subscript as "\n", but when running the test code the same approach did not work.

Subscript Example

```swift
app.staticTexts["ABC\nEFG\nXYZ."].firstMatch
```

Using predicates instead of subscript works for me however:

```swift
import XCTest

 extension XCUIElementQuery {
     func matching(multilineLabel label: String) -> XCUIElementQuery {
         matching(NSPredicate(format: "label == %@", label))
     }
 }
```

Usage Example:

```swift
app.staticTexts.matching(multilineLabel: "ABC\nEFG\nXYZ.").firstMatch
```

Comment: When doing this I get: "This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key text."